# Are there legal issues hosting an Open Source software project on github which uses strong cryptography?

Tags: cryptography

Let's say i code a program under an Open Source license like the GPL which uses strong cryptography in a country which has no restrictions about doing so, and no restrictions in making the software publicly available, like hosting on a hosting provider like github for example.

---

As [of this post](https://github.blog/2017-10-12-evolution-of-our-data-centers/) github stores all or part of the data it is hosting in several datacenters located on the northern american continent. I have [read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_cryptography#Legal_issues) software incorporating strong cryptography falls under a special USA law about ammunition and as i know even written stuff about implementation of strong cryptography is prohibited to export.

---

So when pushing my local git repo to an account on github.com, does legal issues arise ? If so, what are good alternatives ?

Comment: I know of no problems as far as US law goes.

Answer (score 0):

No, the ammo law no longer applies. There is no restriction.

See, Bernstein v. United States. A a set of court cases brought by Daniel J. Bernstein challenging restrictions on the export of cryptography from the United States.

Also DJB created the delightful curve25519 and it's twisted Edwards variant Ed25519.

Comment: [In the wikipedia article ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_v._United_States) about the cases is noted: _The government modified the regulations again, substantially loosening them..._ , so regulations are still intact ? Looks more like there is an actual regulation but no actual enforcement of the law. So any time the government still can decide to act accordingly to the law. A bit unsure to accept your answer so.